# texture(sampler2DArrray, vec3(UV, layer)) only gives first texture for all layers

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, textures, texture-mapping

Code:

```
glGenTextures(1, &textureArray);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, textureArray);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, textureArray);
glTexStorage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 1, GL_RGB8, 512, 512, textureNodes.size());

for(int i = 0; i < textureNodes.size(); i++)
{
    textureNodes[i]->texture->Resize(512, 512);
    glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, 0, 0, i, 512, 512, 1, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureNodes[i]->GetData());
}

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0);
```

GLSL:

Try 1.

```
   FragColor = vec4(texture(_Textures, vec3(TexCoord, 0)).rgb, 1.0f);
```

Try 2.

```
   FragColor = vec4(texture(_Textures, vec3(TexCoord, 2)).rgb, 1.0f);
```

Try 3.

```
   FragColor = vec4(texture(_Textures, vec3(TexCoord, 0.5)).rgb, 1.0f);
```

All gives the first texture(0) although there are 4 textures loaded.

Comment: Are you sure that `textureNodes[i]` are different data?

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes 100% sure they are completely different

Comment: The code looks fine to me. I guess the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @BDL this is all the code related to OpenGL rest is mainly UI stuff still if you think they may be relevant here is the full source https://jaysmito101.github.io/TerraForge3D/documentation/d8/dca/_shader_texture_manager_8cpp_source.html